# Jquery slideDown

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, slidedown

I think i writte something bad because i can´t get the effect slideDown works fine , i want when click show the div in slide down but slow and at the moment show as hasn´t effect and show very fast

**My code :**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery(".login_data_open").click(function() {


jQuery("#login_data_content").slideDown("slow");    

});

});


<div id="login_data_content" style="display:none;"></div>
<div class="login_data_open">Open Div</div>
```

It´s possible i writte bad because i think all it´s ok and it must show ok and show slow and no all in one second

Thank´s for the help

Comment: It works as expected, so what is your issue?  http://jsfiddle.net/k248q/

Comment: there is no content inside the first div , that's the only problem :)

Comment: If you want to add some specific time, you can add time in function like jQuery("#login_data_content").slideDown("2000");

Comment: @kruti no need of `""` for 2000

Answer (score 0):

HTML Sample

```
 <div id="login_data_content" style="display:none;">HIDDEN CONTENT<br><br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id estlaborum.
</div>


 <div class="login_data_open">Open Div</div>
```

JavaScript Sample

```
 $(".login_data_open").click(function () {
     $("#login_data_content").slideDown(5000);
 });
```

If "slow" is too fast for you then you can enter in the number of milliseconds you would like for the effect to take place in.